# How do I determine the architecture for deep NN training according to the number of examples?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

As the title says, how can I determine the architecture or build a reasonable model for training a neural network with regards to the number of examples?

For example, assuming that I have roughly 50 thousand images and I have successfully converted all data to fit the model which means they are ready for training, how can I choose a model that is suitable for training a neural network? I am a little bit confused sometimes when I have data but I did not know how to initiate a model for training NN.

Comment: There's typically not a silver bullet in terms of architecture (number of layers, number of units per layer) and it often varies depending on your data, size of images, etc. Since you're training on images, you'll want to use convolutional layers, but there's really no perfect answer to the architecture that will best suit your data

Comment: Thanks for you comment. Yes, I know basic things. But it is really hard to choose a proper architecture, and when I try to implement it then it makes me confused as I try different ways. What if my image size is (130, 130, 3), do you have any further suggestion?

Comment: Are you talking about developing an architecture from scratch or about taking an existing one?

Comment: Hi! Regarding your question about the shape of your image: I think you may have come across MNIST example they use 28x28x1 input. As you know 28*28 is pixel size of one image and 1 is the number of channels. So if you have a 130x130x3 image you have to change your **Input Placeholder's** shape [None,130x130x3] . Let me know for further confusions

Answer (score 1):

### Fine tuning is the way

Sometimes you have a pre-trained CNN that you can use as a starting point for your domain. For more about fine tuning [You can check here](http://cs231n.github.io/transfer-learning/).

According to this, my advice is to fine tune a pre-trained Neural Network that you can find in Keras ([This page, under "Available models"](https://keras.io/applications/)) or TensorFlow. You can go deeper as far as you are confident with your training set!

In any case, you need to see the number of samples per class rather than the absolute number of images in your training set. If you are confident you can choose a Deep Learning SOA architecture and try to train it from zero.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. What if I have 50 classes and 1000 images for each class? Do you have any further suggestion?

Comment: In that case I would go for a fine tuning the FC layer of a pre-trained network trying the performance with this set.
Keep in mind that I don't know the domain and I am basing my answer on pure intuition!
Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot it does help.